# How to calculate the total number of iteration

Tags: geometry

I am not sure if the Title justifies my problem but I am going to explain here in more detail.

If I have an object like this
[image: S1]

and I want to calculate at what cycle `(which nth cycle)` the object will land at the ground if it is falling vertically at `50m/cycle * nth cycle`.

So in this case, I can calculate the following manually and I know that at `frame=4` it lands at the ground.

```
| frame | constantFallCalulation| Fall@nth frame | posYCalculation | posY  | posY>0 |
| ----- | ----------------------| ---------------| --------------- | ----- | ------ |
| 0     |                       |                |                 | 400   | TRUE   |
| 1     | 1*-50                 | -50            | 400+(-50)       | 350   | TRUE   |
| 2     | 2*-50                 | -100           | 350+(-100)      | 250   | TRUE   |
| 3     | 3*-50                 | -150           | 250+(-150)      | 100   | TRUE   |
| 4     | 4*-50                 | -200           | 100+(-200)      | -100  | FALSE  |
```

But what is the mathemetical formula that would give me the correct frame number for an unknown distance(posY)?

Once I know that formula, I want to convert that calculation to `javascript`. The intenet is to know the total frame number beforehand, so that I ask javascript to pefrom the calculation of posY for that many cycles only, rather than providing an arbitary array of a large number to perform this calcualtion in loop.

Thank you in adavnce.

Comment: Does your object fall with constant speed or does it fall under the effects of gravity (constant acceleration)? In any case, you should use the appropriate formulas from physics (laws of motion) to predict the position of your object, and the time it takes to hit the ground

Comment: Do you know how can I convert what I described into a mathematical formula for now? It would resolve my issue for a starter.

Comment: If you want the number of frames when the bottom of the object touches the ground, then we might need the height of the object.

Comment: Let's assume the  height of the object is 100 unit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the total vertical distance be $y$ (in meters) and the number of frames be $n$ (positive integer). We have,
$$y-50(1+2+\cdots+n)\le 0\implies y\le25n(n+1)$$
Solving the quadratic $n^2+n-\frac{y}{25}\ge 0$, since $n$ is the least such integer,
$$n=\left\lceil \frac{\sqrt{4y+25}-5}{10} \right\rceil$$

Comment: Elided here in the first step is explicit mention of the rule that $1+2+\cdots+n=n(n+1)/2$, which is a formula for the $n$th triangular number (which is the question being asked).

Comment: @SathvikAcharya thanks for the answer. Please allow me some time to apply this into my production element to see the animation is doing what I intended for a differing number of objects with various posY.

Comment: @SathvikAcharya for `posY=600`, I applied your formula like this `(SQRT(4*600+25)-5)/10 [try in excel]` which gives me `4.4244` which is not correct. The correct frame value should be `5`. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. It is also possible that I wrongly understood the mathematical notation.

Comment: @smpa01 Changing the floor function to ceiling function should fix my error. Please check if it works :)

Comment: Thanks @SathvikAcharya in `javascript` `Math.ceil((Math.sqrt(4*y+25)-5)/10);` worked. BTW, how do I account for an `unknown Fall` value in this? If I want to apply different fall value to different objects, such as `50,75,100` respectively for `obj1.posY = 600; obj2.posY=400; obj3.posY=200`. What would be the composite formula for unknow Y and unknown fall constant?

Comment: Yes like `50*nthCycle`, `75*nthCycle`, `100*nthCycle`.

Comment: It would be $n=\left\lceil \frac{\sqrt{1+(8y/s)}-1}{2} \right\rceil$ where $s$ the speed.